# In C++, how do I link a program with libpng/zlib/loadpng in a MacOS X?

Tags: c++, macos, zlib, libpng, allegro

Umm... kinda self explanatory. I use Xcode 4 and Allegro.

Comment: Probably not self explanatory enough.  You might want to add some details about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far if you expect any help.

Comment: I've tried putting -lpng, -zlib, and lloadpng in other linker flags. I'm trying to load a png into a bitmap (see Allegro Bitmap Commands Return Black Screen).

Comment: Are you getting a linking error? What does it say?

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Target list, Build Settings, search for "Other linker flags" and add "-lz".

Comment: I keep reading that you have to use the -lz flag, but can't find it referenced in the documentation anywhere. It does work, but I want to know why? How do you know this?

Comment: -lz means link with libz, which is the name of the binary produced by zlib. Analogously, for libpng you'd add -lpng and so on.

Comment: wow that was quick! Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 4):

To link zlib, you need to use -lz as a compiler flag.